# Amcharts Line Chart with scroll and zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

I have amcharts line chart with scroll and I need to display its legend only based on zoomed data. So the problem is how to setup legend displaying data from selected period instead displaying all data from full history.

Any ideas or thoughts would be awesome.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vcn3vnq6/57/ So if you don't see airplanes on a graph then It shouldn't be in the legend. Of course, I can disable it but imagine 60 categories or more. I want to make visible only zoomed categories for example for export purposes.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible.While AmCharts can display the values in the current zoom period through `periodTextValue`, it cannot remove legend markers based on the current zoom period as they are based on the contents of the graphs array.